# Python scrapy if string not None

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using the python library scrapy and I'm getting a return value on a xpath response in certain iterations, however, others I'm getting returned a:
`"(None,)"` value. 
I only want to yield the value if it's not `"(None,)"`.

I've tried the following:

`if option1 not None:`

but it still prints the `"(None,)"` to output.

Any direction would be appreciated.

UPDATE, HERE IS MY FULL CODE:

```
import scrapy

class StreakSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'streak_spider'
    start_urls = ['http://streak.espn.com/en/?date=20181026']
def parse(self, response):
    GAME_SELECTOR = '.matchup-container'

    for game in response.css(GAME_SELECTOR):
        QUESTION_SELECTOR = '.gamequestion strong ::text'
        TIME_SELECTOR = '.startTime ::text'
        SPORT_SELECTOR = '.sport-description ::text'
        WINNER1_SELECTOR = '.winner ::text'
        OPTION1_SELECTOR = './/span/strong/a/text()'
        question = game.css(QUESTION_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        time = game.css(TIME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        sport = game.css(SPORT_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        winner1 = game.css(WINNER1_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
        option1 = game.xpath(OPTION1_SELECTOR).extract_first(),

        #if option1 != '"(None,)"':
        #if option1 is not None:
        if option1:
            yield {
                    'option1': option1,
            }
```

Comment: To clarify: are you getting a _string_ `"(None,)"`? If so, you have to compare your `option1` to `"(None,)"`, not to `None`.

Comment: Well that's the thing I'm not sure of, I don't know how scrapy handles it, but I've tried both ```if "None" in options1:``` and  ```if options1 != '"(None,)"'```` , but they both did not work.

Comment: What is the `type` of the returned value?

Comment: not sure, won't let me print type, just posted my full code.

Answer (score 0):

`(None,)` is `tuple`

You must be using `.extract()`, so I suggest use `.extract_first()` to get only first results

Comment: I'm using extract_first(), I'm trying to scrap espn streak for cash website, won't let me post my full code cause it's too long apparently